# ec2 hosted app not opening on mobile phone

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2

I have hosted a small app on aws ec2 instance which is [here](http://ec2-52-14-161-145.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/). I have used react on front-end served by node server. This app was running fine till yesterday but today I noticed that my app is opening fine on laptop or computer only. When opened on mobile phone, the browser just continues to load and I receive a blank page after some time.This is happening only in phone.
The homepage of app is:

```
<html>
    <head><title>
        my-app
    </title></head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index_bundle1.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I also notice that as soon as I remove the script from above file, it starts to run fine even on mobile phone. So that looks .js file is possibly creating some problem here. I made absolutely no changes from yesterday.

I asked this problem on aws forum, but I got no response from there.
Would be glad to receive any help.
Thank you!

Comment: Any error you can provide?

Comment: I'm getting absolutely no error. Is it due to overusage of ec2 instance?

Comment: But I don't understand why it is opening on laptop

Comment: Did you click on the link. Is it opening at your end?

Comment: Okk, now it is also not opening on laptop

Comment: It does works in my phone mate

Comment: does it?? But why not on mine.

Comment: This opens on my phone and laptop as well. Can check security groups on EC2? Or NACL on subnets? Is there anything which is blocking requests from mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Check your inbound rule in Security Group
If inbound type is of **http** then your url should be starting with `http://ec2-52-14-161-145.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`
If you have already defined inbound type as **https** then your url should be starting with `https://ec2-52-14-161-145.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`
[image]